# Languages without orthographic stress marks that still have words that differ based on stress

Tags: phonology, morphology, orthography

Wondering about languages with stress that don't mark it orthographically. For example, the only two languages I know of that actually mark stress are Ancient Greek and Spanish. It seems that marking stress with things like acute accents is the edge case instead of the norm.

Instead of asking [Why do some languages (like Spanish) need accent marks, but some don’t (like English)?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-languages-like-Spanish-need-accent-marks-but-some-don%E2%80%99t-like-English), I am wondering if there are any examples of languages that (a) have stress when speaking, where (b) the stress changes the meaning of the word, and yet (c) they don't annotate it orthographically.

This would mean that there could be one *written form* of a word, yet multiple different meanings. I know [Chinese maps written words to multiple meanings](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31468/the-max-number-of-characters-that-map-to-a-single-pronunciation), and we have that too in English with `plant` meaning at least two different things. But while we do have stress in English, we don't annotate it, and we don't have (at least from my understanding) any cases where there is a word that is pronounced like `fubár` and another pronounced `fúbar`, such that they mean different things. If we did have that, then I'm not sure how you would figure out from context (when reading) that this case of `fubar` is supposed to be pronounced `fubár` while that case is supposed to be pronoucced `fúbar`.

So I'm wondering though if any language does have this problem. That is, phonologically they have stress on a word, yet orthographically they don't annotate it, *and yet* the stress causes the word to mean different things. Wondering what some of those languages are, if any.

Comment: English has many word pairs like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun e.g. **sub**ject vs sub**ject**

Comment: Italian marks stress "sometimes", namely when the last written letter in a word is a vowel and the stress falls on it (example: *parlò*, "he/she spoke", versus *parlo*, "I speak"), and "optionally" when there is ambiguity: a widely known example is *prìncipi* (princes) versus *princìpi* (principles). So you could argue then that stress *is* marked in minimal pairs, but this is not done consistently, and there are many cases not as well-known as *principi*, where a writer won't even realize there is a minimal pair at play, and context will make the intended word obvious to any reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from English (progress (V) vs. progress (N); permit (V) vs. permit (N)), Russian has contrastive stress e.g. [ˈmuka] "agony", [muˈka] "flour" spelled мука. As far as I know stress is not written in ordinary writing, but may be indicated in dictionaries (as we do in English). German has examples like ˈumschreiben ("rewrite") vs. umˈschreiben ("paraphrase"). There are cases such as modern Arabic dialects where there are minimal pairs like [kaˈtabit] "I wrote" vs. [ˈkatabit] "she wrote" (from the Palestinian dialect Brame worked on). I think one would write كتبت in both cases, but that brings us to the question of what form of Arabic is being written, when one writes. The stress difference is predictable, if you know which vowels are underlying and which are epenthetic.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is languages with phonemic stress that don't mark it as part of their orthography. Although English doesn't mark stress orthographically, it is phonemic and there are [minimal pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair): for example, the verb *import* /ɪmˈpɔrt/ vs. the noun *import* /ˈɪmpɔrt/ (source and other examples [here](http://blogjam.name/?p=9151)). Hebrew also has minimal pairs such as /ˈoxel/ "food" vs. /oˈxel/ "eat," both spelled אוכל.